# Instancemethod object is not iterable (AirPi) (Python)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I got *ERROR:Exception during output: 'instancemethod' object is not iterable* when debugging this AirPi code from https://github.com/haydnw/AirPi/blob/master/outputs/ubidots.py

This suppose to upload my sensor data to the Ubidots server.

*I'd put my correct token and variable ID inside the configuration file for this AirPi.

```
requiredSpecificParams = ["token"]
optionalSpecificParams = ["showcost",
                  "ID-BMP085-temp",
                  "ID-BMP085-pres",
                  "ID-DHT22-hum",
                  "ID-DHT22-temp",
                  "ID-LDR",
                  "ID-TGS2600",
                  "ID-MiCS-2710",
                  "ID-MiCS-5525",
                  "ID-Microphone",
                  "ID-Raingauge"
                  ]

def __init__(self, config):
    super(Ubidots, self).__init__(config)        
    self.token = self.params["token"]
    if "showcost" in self.params:
        self.showcost = self.params["showcost"]
    else:
        self.showcost = False
    self.ubivariables = {}
    for key, value in self.params.iteritems():
        if key[:3] == "ID-":
            if value:
                self.ubivariables[key[3:]] = value

def output_data(self, datapoints, dummy):
    """Output data.
    Output data in the format stipulated by the plugin. Calibration
    is carried out first if required.
    Because this particular plugin (ubidots) does not show time, the
    third argument (normally called 'sampletime') is called 'dummy'
    to facilitate compliance with pylint.
    Args:
        self: self.
        datapoints: A dict containing the data to be output.
        dummy: datetime representing the time the sample was taken.
    Returns:
        boolean True if data successfully output to Ubidots; False if
            not
    """
    if self.params["calibration"]:
        datapoints = self.cal.calibrate(datapoints)
    payload = []
    for point in datapoints:
        for ubivariablename, ubivariableid in self.ubivariables.iteritems():
            if point["sensor"] == ubivariablename:
                if point["value"] is not None:
                    thisvalue = {}
                    thisvalue["variable"] = ubivariableid
                    thisvalue["value"] = point["value"]
                    payload.append(thisvalue)
                    break
    headers = {'Accept': 'application/json; indent=4', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Auth-Token': self.token}
    url = "http://things.ubidots.com/api/v1.6/collections/values"
    req = None
    cost = 0
    try:
        req = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    except Exception, e:
        print("ERROR: Failed to contact the Ubidots service.")
        print("ERROR: " + str(e))
        return False
    for response in req.json:
        if response["status_code"] is not 201:
            print("ERROR: Ubidots responded with an error for one of the values.")
            return False
        else:
            cost += 1
    if self.showcost:
        print("Ubidots upload cost " + str(cost) + " dots.")
    return True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for response in req.json:
```

According to [the documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content), `json` is a method and must be called, so this should be:

```
for response in req.json():
```

In the future it is helpful to include just as much of your code as is necessary to reproduce the problem, and to include the complete error message with traceback.

Comment: Thanks..really helpful. Will do Sir. :)